# After adding TextView: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a Navigation Drawer and Frame Layout. I would like to show a TextView at the bottom. I have put the FrameLayout and TextView in LinearLayout. As soon as I run the activity, I'm getting this error.

Here's the logcat:

```
01-22 19:43:20.862 18091-18091/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1042)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5704)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2731)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17908)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1418)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6628)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Me
```

*acivity_home.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*app_bar_home.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Jatt"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/offline" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*content_home.xml* (Error comes here due to TextView and maybe, LinearLayout too)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.parassidhu.cdlumaths.Home"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello hi"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure your `DrawerLayout` height is `match_parent`

in your `app_bar_home` layout remove drawer layout tag:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Jatt"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/offline" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

you are already adding it to `acivity_home.xml`

Comment: Didn't work. Yes DrawerLayout's height is match_parent as you can see in the code in main post.

Comment: I removed the DrawerLayout tag but still app crashes with same error :(

Comment: What I did: rebuild project, uninstalled apk, start build again, tried. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.system_pref_sys_log);
}
```

try this in your activity. It works for me.

also see whether you are apply theme for the relevant activity definition in manifest.xml if then remove it and try it. if then do not need to follow above code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because I added the drawyerLayout under a relative layout. 
So to solved it I had to specify the context on the RelativeLayout as my activity.

> tools:mContext=".activities.MainActivity"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:mContext=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
...
```